Django serializer depth doesn't serialize nested models
I use django and react and I want to make some workspaces where they have inside channel instances.
Models.py

class Workspace(models.Model):

    channels = models.ManyToManyField('Channel', related_name='channels', blank=True)



Serializers.py
class WorkspaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Workspace
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 2

Views.py
@api_view(['POST'])
def getworkspace(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        workspace = Workspace.objects.filter(id=request.POST['id']).first()

        serializer = WorkspaceSerializer(workspace, many=False)

    return Response(serializer.data)

Then I use axios to fetch the data

axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/getworkspace/', formData, {headers: {'Content-type':     'multipart/form-data'}}).then(res=>{

   setWorkspace(res?.data)
})

console.log(workspace)


What I was expecting was for workspace channel to be serialized and me be able to access it but instead I get this {id, 1, channels: [1]}
What can I do, I have changed the depth to even 10 but it still doesn't work. If I use shell and serialize it from there like this:
from main.models import *
from main.serializers import *
workspace = Workspace.objects.filter(id=1).first()
serializer = WorkspaceSerializer(workspace, many=False)
print(serializer.data)

It works perfectly.
I believe the problem starts from the view because when I print print(serializer.data) from there channels isn't being serialized.

change request.POST['id'] to request.data.get('id') because when sending data with axios, you're likely sending it as JSON, not as form data and also what I know is depth option doesn't automatically serialize ManyToMany fields deeply, you need to explicitly specify the serializer for the related model

@Bhargav I changed it but the problem is still the same.
